# Docusign Embedded Signing - How can i increase the embedded url expiry time?

Tags: docusignapi

Since Docusign embedded url expires in 5 minutes, how can i increase the expire time. In my case the envelope has 7 pages and around 20 initials and 5 signatures required from the user. So if the expire time remains 5 minutes then url will expire midway between the signing ceremony. How i should handle this scenario or is there anyway to increase the expire time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signing URL's time to live is separate from an Active Signing Session's time to live - a user won't be kicked out of the signing session because the five minutes expired.

Chaining signing sessions together by using one session's URL as the return URL for the other is not supported. Instead, you should implement a landing page that request the next signing session once the first one is complete.